# Is Local Miss Rate equivalent to the Global Miss Rate for the lowest level of a Cache System?

Tags: caching

Is it correct to say the following statements:

Statement 1: **Global Miss Rate for an L2 cache is the same as the Local Miss Rate for an L2 cache.** Since for a memory reference accessing L2, to miss L1 and L2 is equivalent to missing L2, because because it has already missed L1 by virtue of attempting to access L2 (For a system of 2 hierarchical caches - L1 and L2)

Statement 2: **The Global Miss Rate for an L1 cache is the same as Local Miss Rate for L1 Cache** (For a system of 2 hierarchical caches - L1 and L2)

Statement 3: **The Global Miss Rate for an Ln cache is the same as the Local Miss Rate for Ln cache** (For a system of 2 hierarchical caches - L1, L2, L3,..., Ln)

Answer (score 8):

Let me answer this as clearly as possible.

**Local Miss Rate** = Number of Misses in this cache/Number of references to this cache

**Global Miss Rate** = No. of Misses in this cache/Total number of references made by the processor

**Statement 1: False**

Explanation:

1. No. of accesses to L2 = No. of misses in L1
2. Total number of references made by the processor = Number of accesses to L1
   (Since all memory references made by the processor are first served (tried to be served) by the L1 cache.

Therefore for L2 cache,

Local MR = Number of misses in L2 / Number of misses in L1

Global MR = Number of misses in L2 / Number of accesses to L1

**So, for L2, Local MR != Global MR**

**Statement 2: True**

Explanation:

For L1 cache,

Local MR = Number of misses in L1 / Number of accesses to L1

Global MR = Number of misses in L1 / Total number of references made by the processor

Total number of references made by the processor = Number of accesses to L1 (Since all memory references made by the processor are first served (tried to be served) by the L1 cache.

**So, for L1, Local MR = Global MR**

**Statement 3: False**, Correction - For a system of n hierarchical caches L1, L2,...,Ln

Explanation:

This statement is analogous to Statement 1. It means that for L2 in 2-level system, L3 in 3-level system, L4 in 4-level system and so on...

We proved that it is false for L2 in 2-level system in Statement 1. Same explanation follows for the rest.

**Thus, for Ln in n-level hierarchical system, Local MR != Global MR**